# Trying to put together all values from a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I have a list of populations which I get using this query.

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable<File>().Select(x => x.pop);
```

What I want to do is add together all the items found in the list and get a total population. I have tried to use the .sum() but I can't get it to work. I have also tried to use the aggregate method. But it says  The Aggregate query operator is not supported. It says the same when I try to use the sum method. Here's is what the full method looks like now.

```
private long TotalPopulation()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient();
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("TestData");
        var collection = db.GetCollection<File>("josonfiles");

        var query = collection.AsQueryable<File>().Select(x => x.pop);

        var result = query.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable<File>().Select(x => x.pop).ToList();
```

Comment: He says, he has already tried that many moons ago. Actually, he is using the old legacy API. With newer asynch 2.x API, x.pop  meant populations as he says, then simply MongoDb aggregate would do. Even with Linq approach, he could have use Sum().

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the database doesn't support those operations (or the client doesn't know how to translate them). If there's no other way to do the aggregation, you'll have to do it on the client, not the server. One way to do this is to force the query to execute on the server before doing the aggregation:

```
collection.AsQueryable<File>().Select(x => x.pop).AsEnumerable().Sum();
```

Of course, if you have a lot of results in the database, you're going to be downloading every single one of them. But well, that's one of the costs of using a non-queryable database :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay So i have figured it out myself. My query was a IEnumrableList so by making it a List< T > the aggregate method works. like this.

```
var query = collection.AsQueryable<File>().Select(x => x.pop).ToList();
```